# Why there is black color shed on the upper side and left side on textbox border in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on ASP.Net and a black color shed always appears on the upper side and left side of `textbox` border. Even when I change the border color it appears. I want to remove this black color.

These are the two `textbox`. As you can see the black color:

> [image]

Textbox code is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="241px" CssClass="newStyle3 textboxcurve" Height="32px"></asp:TextBox>
```

and CSS are:

```
.textboxcurve {
    -webkit-border-radius: 2000px;
}

.newStyle3 {
    font-family: "Century Schoolbook";
}
```

Comment: A shed is a **garden house**... I don't think you mean that, so please explain yourself better. Also: you need to give sample code, and make sure it reproduces your issue, as stated here in great detail: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can consider it as black color mark on upper border and left border of text box. Its just a simple textbox, there is no code behind it. When I change the border  color it just makes its more darker but only on top & left side of textbox not on the other 2 side. Hope this makes you understand my problem @PeterB

Comment: Please reread my comment: you need to give a thorough code sample, or else this question is not answerable and is likely to be closed. You can [edit] the question for that.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an image of what your'e asking about? Textboxes have a 3d border by default, making them look like they're "holes" in the surrounding page. Perhaps this is what you mean?

Comment: I cannot add image as stackoverflow shows popup. But I have added the code of textbox. And I think you are right, it might be 3d border. So how to remove it. @ZoharPeled

Comment: I have added the code, please review it. Thanks @PeterB

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "shadow"? If so set the border in css `border: 1px solid red;`

Comment: yes its a kind of shadow. but if i change the color to red then it makes the border color into more darker red. @VDWWD

Comment: Yeah, that's the 3D border default "inset". If you change the border using css it should be removed.

Comment: Inspect the CSS code using your navigator. The css property you added might be overriden by the default CSS of the element. 
If you just want to remove the black border color, you can just remove the border by doing : border : none;. As a matter of fact, any change you do on the border should be applied. If it is not, this means something has the priority over your css class and you might want to check it.
You can use " border: none! important;" to guarantee that it works but i do not recommend  it as the important property should be used with great care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the border of TextBox you can set BorderStyle to "None":

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you like to have rounded corners you can use CSS border-radius property. The final code will be as following:

```
 <style>
    .RoundedCorner {
        border-radius: 25px;
        background: #73AD21;
        width: 200px;
        height: 25px; 
    }
</style>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" CssClass="RoundedCorner"></asp:TextBox>
```